# React - hide and show individual element

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to toggle show/hide on individual elements. I thought the key={item._id} will be enough to toggle the individual items, but when clicking the toggle button every element is revealed.

This is my attempt: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-torvalds-xnkt1?file=/src/App.js

I would really appreciate any suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated and  working code [`here`](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-surf-s9xl5)

Changes in code:

**In list data structure**

```
const list = [
  {
    _id: "1",
    book: "Witcher 1",
    author: "Andrzej Sapkowski",
    show: false // add additional key to toggel
  },
  ...
];
```

**In constructor**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      books: list // defined books state
    };
  }
```

**in handleShow**

```
handleShow = event => {
    console.log(event.target.id);
    const books = this.state.books;
    const bookId = event.target.id; // get selected book id

    for (let index = 0; index < books.length; index++) {
      if (bookId === books[index]._id) {
        books[index].show = !books[index].show; //toggle the element 
      }
    }
    this.setState({ books });
  };
```

**In render:**

```
render() {
const listItem = this.state.books.map(item => { //use state to iterate
  return (
    <div key={item._id} className="flex p-4">
      <div key={item._id}>{item.book}</div>
      <button
        id={item._id} //add key to get the selected book
        onClick={this.handleShow}
        className="px-4 font-bold bg-gray-300"
      >
        toggle
      </button>
      <div>{item.show ? <div>{item.author}</div> : null}</div> // use key  `show` to toggle it 
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: RIYAJ KHAN thanks you soooooo much it works!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can split that in to a component and maintain the toggle state there which is "show". I have updated my answer in your CodeSandbox link [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-leakey-e8beq?file=/src/App.js)

```
//App.js

import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "./styles/tailwind-pre-build.css";
import Book from './Book';

const list = [
  {
    _id: "1",
    book: "Witcher 1",
    author: "Andrzej Sapkowski"
  },
  {
    _id: "2",
    book: "Witcher 2",
    author: "Andrzej "
  },
  {
    _id: "3",
    book: "Witcher 3",
    author: "Andrzej Sapkowski"
  }
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  render() {
    const listItem = list.map(item => {
      return (
        <div className="flex p-4">
          <div key={item._id}>{item.book}</div>
          {/* <button
            onClick={this.handleShow}
            className="px-4 font-bold bg-gray-300"
          >
            toggle
          </button>
          <div>{this.state.show ? <div>{item.author}</div> : null}</div> */}
          <Book item={item}/>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="text-2xl">
        <div>List of books</div>
        {listItem}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Book.js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "./styles/tailwind-pre-build.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false
    };
  }

  handleShow = () => {
    this.setState({
      show: !this.state.show
    });
  };

  render(){
    return(
      <>
          <button
            onClick={this.handleShow}
            className="px-4 font-bold bg-gray-300"
          >
            toggle
          </button>
          <div>{this.state.show ? <div>{this.props.item.author}</div> : null}</div>
      </>
    )    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just change the show variable in the state to take the index of the element like this :

```
 handleShow = (idx) => {
    this.setState({
      show: idx
    });
  };
```

and your constructor becomes :

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: -1
    };
  }
```

And your list becomes :

```
 const listItem = list.map(item => {
      return (
        <div className="flex p-4">
          <div key={item._id}>{item.book}</div>
          <button
            onClick={() => this.handleShow(item._id)}
            className="px-4 font-bold bg-gray-300"
          >
            toggle
          </button>
          <div>{this.state.show === item._id ? <div>{item.author}</div> : null}</div>
        </div>
      );
    });
```

I think that will do it !

Answer (score 2):

you can save `list` into state and add a `isToggle` prop for every object, and `handleShow` change the isToggle state of clicked target item, code will look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "./styles/tailwind-pre-build.css";

const list = [
  {
    _id: "1",
    book: "Witcher 1",
    author: "Andrzej Sapkowski",
    isToggle: false,
  },
  {
    _id: "2",
    book: "Witcher 2",
    author: "Andrzej ",
    isToggle: false,
  },
  {
    _id: "3",
    book: "Witcher 3",
    author: "Andrzej Sapkowski",
    isToggle: false,
  }
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list
    };
  }

  handleShow = (e) => {
    const index = this.state.list.findIndex(t => t._id === e.currentTarget.dataset.id);
    const list = [...this.state.list];
    list[index].isToggle = !list[index].isToggle;
    this.setState({ list });
  };

  render() {
    const listItem = list.map(item => {
      return (
        <div className="flex p-4">
          <div key={item._id}>{item.book}</div>
          <button
            data-id={item._id}
            onClick={this.handleShow}
            className="px-4 font-bold bg-gray-300"
          >
            toggle
          </button>
          <div>{item.isToggle ? <div>{item.author}</div> : null}</div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="text-2xl">
        <div>List of books</div>
        {listItem}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show them toggled individually you can do like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "./styles/tailwind-pre-build.css";

const list = [
  {
    _id: "1",
    book: "Witcher 1",
    author: "Andrzej Sapkowski"
  },
  {
    _id: "2",
    book: "Witcher 2",
    author: "Andrzej "
  },
  {
    _id: "3",
    book: "Witcher 3",
    author: "Andrzej Sapkowski"
  }
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: false,
      showId: null,
    };
  }

  handleShow = (id) => {
    this.setState({
      showId: id
    });
  };

  render() {
    const listItem = list.map(item => {
      return (
        <div className="flex p-4">
          <div key={item._id}>{item.book}</div>
          <button
            onClick={() => this.handleShow(item._id)}
            className="px-4 font-bold bg-gray-300"
          >
            toggle
          </button>
          <div>{this.state.showId === item._id ? <div>{item.author}</div> : null}</div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="text-2xl">
        <div>List of books</div>
        {listItem}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```